# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined discord bot problem

Tags: node.js, discord, bots

Hi I am using visual studio and node .js and I am making a discord bot, I have this problem:

```
    Waiting for the debugger to disconnect…
C:\Users\user\Desktop\POG BOT\index.js:17
bot.commands.set(props.help.name,props)
^

TypeError: Cannot read property ‘name’ of undefined
at C:\Users\user\Desktop\POG BOT\index.js:17:41
at C:\Users\user\Desktop\POG BOT\index.js:15:16
at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:171:23)
```

**My code is:**

```
    const Discord = require(‘discord.js’)

const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.commands = new Discord.Collection ();

const fs = require(‘fs’)

bot.on(‘ready’, () => {

console.log('I am here')

fs.readdir('./commands', (err, files) => {

    if(err) return console.log(err)

    let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() == 'js')

    if(jsfile.length == 0 ) {return console.log("No Command bro!")}

    jsfile.forEach(f => {

        let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);

        bot.commands.set(props.help.name,props)

    })

} )
})

bot.on(‘message’, (message) => {

if(message.author.bot) return;

if(message.channel.type !== 'text') return;

let prefix = '!';

let MessageArray = message.content.split (' ');

let cmd = MessageArray[0].slice(prefix.length)

let args = MessageArray.slice(1)

if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

let commandfile = bot.commands.get(cmd);

if(commandfile) {commandfile.run(bot,message,args)}
})

bot.login(“token”)
```

The weird thing is that the bot goes online but the commands don't work. It used to work but one day when I did `node .` the above message popped up. I really don't know what I changed.

Can somebody please help me I am new to programming?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow. For future reference: Please refrain from tagging questions with tags that are irrelevant. I came here from the C# tag, and have no idea how to help you as your problem isn't actually related to C#. But otherwise it seems to a good question for a first time user

Comment: `let props = require(`./commands/${f}`);` You are iterating over each `.js` file and are importing it. Are you certain each of them have `props.help` defined. The error message says it is `undefined`. You could add some debug message what the `${f}` is stuck on and then the content of that file.

Comment: As commented by @tin-nguyen your problem is with your `props` import. Could you share your help.js file ? I'm guessing it exports the function direclty and not an object containing `help` as key